# programmatically find commits in one branch but not the other

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

Given two branches, feature/SomeWork and develop

How do I find the list of commits in feature/SomeWork that have not yet been merged to develop using libgit2sharp?

I am currently programmatically walking through each of the commits and checking to make sure they are present in the target branch

I am hoping there is a more straightforward and faster way of doing it

**Note:**  I need to do this programmatically within my application using *libgit2sharp*, I know the way to do this via command line, but would prefer to avoid shelling out to process and reading output, etc. if possible, thank you

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of determining the common ancestor, and then iterating forward?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `git cherry` command:

```
git cherry -v develop feature/SomeWork
```

That command should list all the commits in feature/SomeWork that are not in develop.

Answer (score 0):

This command should give you what is needed.

```
git log feature/SomeWork ^^develop --no-merges
```

Please note ^^ , one of ^ is used as escape character on windows.